# how do you solve the simultaneous equations 2x + y = 9 and x - 2y = -8 using the matrix method?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

i first convert the bases into a 2x2 matrix and then i multiplied the inverse matrix by the 2x1 e/f matrix of 9 (on top) and -8 (on the bottom)

which gave me x = 5.4 and y = 5
however the answer sheets states that x= 2 and y=5

May i please have some help on where I'm going wrong? Am i not multiplying the signs correctly? thank you for your help.

Comment: your approach is right , just look at the value of inverse , whether it is right , or whether you wrote the matrix wrong

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

In matrix notation we have:
$$
Ax=b
$$ 
with 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
2&1\\1&-2
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad x=\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y
\end{bmatrix}\qquad
b=\begin{bmatrix}
9\\-8
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so $$x=A^{-1}b$$
with
$$
A^{-1}=\frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix}
2&1\\1&-2
\end{bmatrix}
$$